# Can't install yii2 advanced template, migrate command

Tags: php, yii, yii2, migrate

When installed yii2 advanced template collided with the "migrate" problem.
After db creating I tried run yii migrate but receive this exception:

'yii\base\InvalidCallException' with message 'Setting read-only property: yii\console\Application::db'

I don't know why it happens, because config are OK and I can work with db through shell or dBeaver. OS Linux Mint. Thanks for help.

Console command "/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/advanced/yii migrate".

console/config/main-local.php:

```
return [
'bootstrap' => ['gii'],
'modules' => [
    'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module',
],
'db' => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2advanced',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'pw',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
],
];
```

Comment: For  console you should set the same db config  in console/config main.php  or main-local.php

Comment: Thank you, it is help. But now another problem exist. 'Setting read-only property: yii\console\Application::db'

Comment: Which problem ?

Comment: update your question and show me all the main.php  or main-local.php  (console) code ..  and comment e when you have done

Comment: I have posted  an asnwer hope is useful

Comment: Question updated, problem solved, with your help of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you set properly console/config/main.php   (or main-local.php)

in component section  .. db entry

```
return [
'id' => 'app-console',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
'components' => [
     ..... 
    'db' => [

        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db_name',
        'username' => 'your_username',
        'password' => 'your_pwd',
        'charset' => 'utf8',


    ],
```

Comment: @WiAim   . is important .. do the same in your config (frontend and backend )